# RegEx VB.NET part of string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a regex witch searches for dates `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](20)\d\d`.

The problem is that it also returns matches where the match is within another string like `10.10.10.2019` it matches `10.10.2019` as a date. Tried with `\b` at the beginning and end but no luck. Also used `^` and `$` but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use lookarounds to only match in between whitespaces or start/end of string:

```
(?<!\S)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([- /.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])\k<1>20\d\d(?!\S)
^^^^^^^                                                                ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c%5b12%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c3%5b01%5d%29%28%5b-+%2f.%5d%29%28%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c1%5b012%5d%29%5ck%3c1%3e20%5cd%5cd%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=10.10.10.2019%0d%0a10.10.2019+%0d%0a10%2f10%2f10%2f2019%0d%0a+10%2f10%2f2019%0d%0a1-1-2016%0d%0a)

I also suggest to check for the identical separators by capturing the first separator with `([- /.])` and then using `\k<1>` (unambiguous) backreference to match the same value.

Comment: The regex you supplied doesn't recognize this date format 1-1-2016